# Get value of multiple created controls at runtime VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I can get the value of a single control that has been created at run time, that control is a `DateTimePicker`, but i can't get the values of multiple controls. how do i do it?

code:

This is where i add the `DateTimePicker` with every click at run time.

```
Private Sub btnAddTime_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddTime.Click
    Dim Time As New DateTimePicker()
    Dim count As Integer = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of DateTimePicker)().ToList().Count
    Time.Location = New Point(9, (23 * count) + 22)
    Time.Size = New Size(150, 20)
    Time.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time
    Time.ShowUpDown = True
    Time.Name = "DateTimePicker" & (count + 1)
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Time)
End Sub
```

And this is where i get the values of the controls.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each cntrl In Form3.GroupBox1.Controls
        Dim dt As DateTimePicker = Form3.GroupBox1.Controls.Item("DateTimePicker" & (i + 1))
        If DateTime.Now.ToString = dt.Value Then
            MsgBox("P")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I can only get the the value of a created control if only i specified it in the code, i think i can't get the right `Name` of the control. I'm trying to make the program to read every value of the control in another form while the `Timer` ticks. help?

Comment: Why can't you read `dt.Name` within your `For Each` loop?

Comment: uhm tips on how to do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    For Each cntrl In Form3.GroupBox1.Controls
        If TypeOf cntrl Is DateTimePicker Then
            If DateTime.Now.ToString = cntrl.Value Then
                MsgBox("P")
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: or instead, use `For Each cntrol In Form3.GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of DateTimePicker)()` so you won't need to use `If TypeOf...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Master! m(_ _;)m

Comment: No problem pre. Hehe

Comment: pde pla tagalog dito hehe, Salamats idol!